# Is it possible to replace built-in about pages?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am pretty new to developing addons but I'd like to make one that modifies/replaces the about:netError page.

I could not find tutorials or documentation anywhere, is it even possible?

Thank you.

Edit: I need to edit the xhtml file which shows the info about error.

Comment: One way is to listen to the page load and then change it - http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2787683&hilit=+neterror   ---- It might be worth trying to overide it by using the same GUID with this method here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Custom_about:_URLs

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?